# Changes missing after Commit operation in GIT

Tags: git, git-commit

I am trying to commit the changes of files in /webapps folder of my project. I see that, except the first commit, the subsequent commit operations do not make any modification to the /webapps folder.
This problem is happening only when committing changes to /webapps folder.

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: Before changes you make can be committed in the git repository (local or remote), the files that are changed must have been "staged". Did you do something like `git add webapps/*`?

Comment: Is there a line in .gitignore causing files under /webapps to be ignored by git?

Comment: i checked gitignore. it has only an entry /target/ . I ran git status to check if any untracked files are present. But it did not seem to help.
PS: I am using maven build. Will it be related to any maven configuration issue?